# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

While running the code I am getting an error that shows Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget and RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: _column,
        );
      }
  get _column {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        _setTitleText(Constant.shuffle_drinks, 8),
        _setTop10List(
            list: randomCocktailList,
            height: 150,
            width: 300,
            axis: Axis.horizontal,
            listHeight: 150,
            textSize: 14,
            flag: false),
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
      child: _ingredientGrid,
    ),
    _setTitleText(Constant.latest_drink, 8),
    _setTop10List(
        list: latestCocktailList,
        height: 150,
        width: 300,
        axis: Axis.horizontal,
        listHeight: 150,
        textSize: 14,
        flag: false),
    _setTitleText("Popular Drinks", 8),
    Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        _setTop10List(
            list: popularCocktailList,
            height: 150,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            axis: Axis.vertical,
            listHeight: double.maxFinite,
            textSize: 14,
            flag: true),
      ],
    )
  ],
)};
```

Further Code:

```
Widget _setTop10List(
      {Future<List<Cocktail>> list,
      double height,
      double width,
      Axis axis,
      double listHeight,
      double textSize,
      bool flag}) {
    if (axis == Axis.vertical) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Utils.getFutureBuilder(
              list: list,
              height: height,
              width: width,
              axis: axis,
              listHeight: listHeight,
              textSize: textSize,
              flag: flag)
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        height: listHeight,
        child: Utils.getFutureBuilder(
            list: list,
            height: height,
            width: width,
            axis: axis,
            listHeight: listHeight,
            textSize: textSize,
            flag: flag),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _setTitleText(String title, double top) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: top),
      child: Flexible(
//             alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        flex: 1,
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontFamily: "Poppins",
              fontSize: 18,
              letterSpacing: 1,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
```

Comment: Try wrapping one of the inner columns in Expanded() or Flexible()?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup Tried but not helping

Comment: can you add `_setTop10List` and `_setTitleText`

Comment: Please provide the complete code so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: @MohammadHosein Here is the complete code .. https://github.com/yadavmangesh/somras-cocktail-app/blob/master/lib/home/HomeScreen.dart

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have added please have a look

Comment: @pskink I have added full code here

Comment: @pskink ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: @pskink I have also added Error message in the Question. Please have a look

Comment: Are you using any `ListView` , 'GridView` inside your `_column` widget ? @NeerajMehta

Comment: @SwaminathanV No i am not using

Comment: I can see the usage of **`GridView.count` in the Github link you shared in the comment**. Please confirm. @NeerajMehta

Comment: @SwaminathanV Yes I have used

Comment: @SwaminathanV that method is not being called ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Scaffold` with infinite height.  This happens because the `Home` widget in `SomrasMain.dart` places `HomeScreen` in a `SingleChildScrollView`.

The simplest way to fix this would be to remove the `Scaffold` from `HomeScreen`.  You don't need one anyway, since the entire widget is contained in `Home` which already provides a `Scaffold`.

Comment: So what should I return in place of Scaffold??

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both of your FutureBuilder with Expanded and also Wrap your settopList method with Expanded

Comment: Done .. No help